# Vuejs - add different classes in elements generated with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to add a class to a list group create using bootstrap 5 in my vuejs app. I know about class binding but in my case I'm not sure how to proceed. I want that when the user click on an item inside the list, the clicked item get the `disabled active` class and the other elements gets only the `disabled` class. At the moment I have this code in my template

```html
 <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
   <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" v-for="(choice, index) in item.choices" :key="index">
     <small class="" @click.prevent="checkAnswer(item.questionIndex, index)">{{ index }}) {{ choice }}</small>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

The `v-for` loop will generate the elements and when an element is clicked a method is called to check the user choice. In my app script I have this code

```js
export default {
  name: 'Survey',
  data() {
    return {
      n: 0,
      answeredQuestions: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  computed: {
    questions() {
      return this.$store.getters.survey;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showNext() {
      if( this.n < this.questions.length ){
        this.n++
      }
    },
    isAnswered(index) {
      return this.n !== index ? 'hide' : '';
    },
    checkAnswer(questionIndex, choice) {
      this.answeredQuestions.push(true);
      this.showNext();
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

What's the best way to implement the needed class binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of unknowns about the rest of your code (how the questions are handled and switched through, etc.), but here's a working example for a single question. So you'll have to adapt this for having multiple questions in your app, but it should push you in the right direction. I used an inline `:style` attribute in addition to the static styles already present on the `<li>`, but you could move that to a function as suggeted in Peter's answer, if you prefer.

```js
const app = {
  name: 'Survey',
  data() {
    return {
      n: 0,
      questions: [],
      answeredQuestions: [],
      item: {
        questionIndex: 1,
        choices: ['Lorem', 'Ipsum']
      },
      selectedChoice: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {

  },
  computed: {
    questions() {
      return this.$store.getters.survey;
    },
  },
  methods: {
    showNext() {
      if (this.n < this.questions.length) {
        this.n++
      }
    },
    isAnswered(index) {
      return this.n !== index ? 'hide' : '';
    },
    checkAnswer(questionIndex, choice) {
      this.answeredQuestions.push(choice);
      this.showNext();
    }
  }
};
Vue.createApp(app).mount('#app');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.11/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" :class="{disabled: answeredQuestions.length, active: answeredQuestions.includes(index)}" v-for="(choice, index) in item.choices" :key="index" @click.prevent="checkAnswer(item.questionIndex, index)">
      <small class="">{{ index }}) {{ choice }}</small>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions are checked in nodejs under the hood the appe use androidjs. Anyway this is eaxctly what I was trying to do!Just an explaination, whhy you hace used `answeredQuestions.length`? Thank you

Comment: That's what I meant that you have to adapt it to the rest of the code. I just needed something to check that changes once you click on an answer. In your app, you'll probably have muliple questions objects, and you'll need to set a flag specifically for each question containing the selected answer. Then you can check (for example) `question.selectedAnswer`...

Comment: ok, perfect!Thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You search the internet for `vue class binding` and it's the first result that pops up:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

You can use an plain object, object from your data, a function returning an object or simply a string. You can make any attribute dynamic with `v-bind:`, or simply `:`.
Your `checkAnswer()` function can cause a change in classes by manipulating something in `data`, for example.

See tutorial above for example code. Keep in mind `v-bind:class` is the same as `:class`.

The "best way" changes like every week in Vue, just find a way to do it and learn its advantages and disadvantages.

An example would be:

**template**: let a function generate the classes

```html
<small
  :class="getChoiceClasses(item, choice, index)"
  @click.prevent="checkAnswer(item.questionIndex, index)"
>{{ index }}) {{ choice }}</small>
```

**script**: add method

```js
getChoiceClasses(item, choice, index) {
  let classes = {
    active: choice == 1, // for example
    disabled: false, // default
    even: index % 2 == 0
  };

  if (whateverYouNeedToCheck) {
    classes.disabled = true;
  }
  
  return classes;
}
```

A method is a little slower than a value from `data`, but it's very minor and only becomes a problem when you have 100s of calls.

Comment: Not very helpful, I know how to bind a class, If you readed the question you should understand that my problem isn't how to bind a class with vue but how to do it in my use case where I need to bind different classes for elements that are generated using v-for loop. Anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: Same answer. You just create the classes dynamically for every element in the loop. Either by `data`, a function returning an object or a string, ...

Comment: can you provide an example, I'm not sure what do you mean with 'create the classes dynamically for every element in the loop'

Comment: Sure, I have updated the answer. Hope you mean something like that. Also the title of your question should say `v-for` instead of `v-if`, right?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your situation and what you intend to do here I would suggest using the item in the checkAnswer method so that an identifier is used to set a computed property to the current item.questionIndex.

Then you bind the class of each element with a ternary operator condition to check the  questionIndex and return the proper classes string:  <small :class="questionIndex ==  item.questionIndex ? 'disabled active':'disabled'" ...